# Isomorphism of Filtered Objects?

Tags: category-theory, filtrations

Let $\mathscr{C}$ be a category and let $Filt(\mathscr{C})$ denote the category of filtered objects in $\mathscr{C}$. So an object $X$ in $Filt(\mathscr{C})$ look something like $X_0\subset X_1\subset ... \subset X_k=X$. What are isomorphisms in $Filt(\mathscr{C})$? Are they level-wise isomorphisms between the objects?

Comment: The isomorphisms are determined if you know what the morphisms are. But what are the morphisms? You haven't told us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what notion of morphism you want for this category. My gut reaction would be to define morphisms between the filtered objects to be a collection of arrows $X_i \to Y_i$ in $\mathcal{C}$ which commute with the inclusions in the filtration. Indeed, this is the notion of morphism adopted in [this text](https://books.google.co.nz/books?id=2GoFFFG4AoQC&pg=PA235&lpg=PA235&dq=category+of+filtered+objects&source=bl&ots=E6mutMUm1s&sig=46yc_mPCTaPu-BkaaSXUXw6mBkA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiv_b7IrdvNAhVBnpQKHfxaDoYQ6AEIRjAH#v=onepage&q=category%20of%20filtered%20objects&f=false). Then isomorphisms would be level-wise isomorphisms, which additionally must commute with the inclusions.